# java: HttpURLConnection with cyrillic characters

Tags: java, web-services, encoding

I need to do soap request to web service. There are only 2 functions, so I decided to use simple HttpURLConnection so speed up development. 
Here is the test code(don't be afraid of try/catch, it's just a test).

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://doc.ssau.ru/ssau_biblioteka_test/ws/DspaceIntegration.1cws");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic d2Vic2VydmljZTp3ZWJzZXJ2aWNl");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
    try {
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream wr = null;
    try {
        wr = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String myString = "RU/НТБ СГАУ/WALL/Х62/С 232-948516";
    byte bytes[] = new byte[0];
    try {
        bytes = myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String value = "";
    try {
         value = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        wr.writeBytes("<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:imc=\"http://imc.parus-s.ru\">\n" +
                "   <soap:Header/>\n" +
                "   <soap:Body>\n" +
                "      <imc:GetRecordsInfo>\n" +
                "         <imc:Codes>RU/НТБ СГАУ/WALL/Х62/С 232-948516</imc:Codes>\n" +
                "         <imc:Separator>?</imc:Separator>\n" +
                "         <imc:Type>?</imc:Type>\n" +
                "      </imc:GetRecordsInfo>\n" +
                "   </soap:Body>\n" +
                "</soap:Envelope>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        wr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if not Java 5+
    String line;
    try {
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        rd.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So here is the question:
When I do wirteByes with cyrillyc characters, like "RU/НТБ СГАУ/WALL/Х62/С 232-948516", the web service returns 500. If I use only latin or leave empty, then everthing is ok.
What is the right way to encode cyrillyc?

**UPDATE**
Problem solved, used this construction:

```
wr.write(new String("<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:imc=\"http://imc.parus-s.ru\">\n" +
                "   <soap:Header/>\n" +
                "   <soap:Body>\n" +
                "      <imc:GetRecordsInfo>\n" +
                "         <imc:Codes>RU/НТБ СГАУ/WALL/Х62/С 232-948516</imc:Codes>\n" +
                "         <imc:Separator>?</imc:Separator>\n" +
                "         <imc:Type>?</imc:Type>\n" +
                "      </imc:GetRecordsInfo>\n" +
                "   </soap:Body>\n" +
                "</soap:Envelope>").getBytes(charset));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure that what might be going wrong, there are a couple of things you might try.

1)Try a different encoding. Following code might help.

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-16");    
byte[] encodedBytes = myString.getBytes(charset);
```

2)Another thing you can try is guessing the character set of your string.(Please Note : there is no way to guess the character set 100% right every time)

```
byte[] thisAppCanBreak = "this app can break"
        .getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    CharsetDetector detector = new CharsetDetector();
    detector.setText(thisAppCanBreak);
    String tableTemplate = "%10s %10s %8s%n";
    System.out.format(tableTemplate, "CONFIDENCE",
        "CHARSET", "LANGUAGE");
    for (CharsetMatch match : detector.detectAll()) {
      System.out.format(tableTemplate, match
          .getConfidence(), match.getName(), match
          .getLanguage());
    }
```

[This link](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.in/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html) might be helpful too

Comment: @AstralGnome: Hi, I am glad it solved your problem, It would be nice if you can post the solution in the comment so that I can include it in the answer, or else if its a big one you can yourself post the exact answer, it will help the future viewers, in finding the exact solution to this kind of problem. :)